# Remove youtube video device support

Tags: youtube-api

I'm getting youtube video on my website. This video is about devicesupport, and I want remove it and then show the rest of the videos.

How can I remove that video?

I'm using API V2. I know that is obsolete but i don't want update it. Only remove this first video.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

V2 has been officially retired, and will be shut off completely soon. That video is there to alert developers of the need to update their code to V3. Right now, that video will be at the top of any responses; later you'll see that it's the only video that ever gets returned (this should happen early May). and finally the API endpoints will stop responding in late May (returning a 410).

More info, and migration info, can be found here.

http://youtube-eng.blogspot.com/2015/04/bye-bye-youtube-data-api-v2.html